# Are cardinals with the same "continuum function" equal?

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

Let $\kappa, \lambda$ be two infinite cardinals such that for all infinite $\mu, \mu^\kappa = \mu^\lambda$. Is it the case that $\kappa =\lambda$ ?

First of all, clearly if the generalized continuum hypothesis holds, then the answer is yes (just take $\mu = 2^\kappa$, if $\kappa \leq \lambda$).

If we don't assume GCH, then it is well-known that $\mu = 2^\kappa$ is not enough to answer. I was thinking that maybe evaluating at some specifc cardinals such as $\kappa, 2^\kappa,  \aleph_\kappa, \beth_\kappa$ could help, but so far nothing has given me an answer.

It is also possible of course that it's consistent that $\kappa \neq \lambda$, although that would be surprising to me (a bit, with rime you get used to this stuff I guess); if that's the case can we even choose any reasonable$\kappa, \lambda$  ? (e.g. is it consistent that $\kappa = \aleph_0, \lambda = \aleph_1$ ?)

Comment: $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ could be different *finite* (nonzero) cardinals....

Comment: @Henning: Valid remark, of course. I suspect that the intention was to consider infinite cardinals only, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, hence only a comment.

Comment: @Henning : you are of course right. Initially I had put no restrictions on $\mu$, which of course took care of the finite case, but I realized I was actually interested in infinite $\mu$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Suppose that $\kappa<\lambda$, take $\mu=\beth_{\kappa^+}$, then $$\beth_{\kappa^+}^\kappa = \beth_{\kappa^+} <\beth_{\kappa^+}^{\kappa^+} \leq \beth_{\kappa^+}^\lambda.$$

Comment: I assume the strixt inequality follows from König's lemma ? I'll have to look into the cardinal arithmetic of the first inequality for myself ! Thank you !

Comment: @Max Both the equality and the inequality follow from the fact that it's a strong limit with cofinality $\kappa^+$ (so yes I guess that boils down to Konig for the inequality).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen : yes I realized that the equality is easy to prove by elementary considerations anyway