# Does a free algebra over a nontrivial monad have a well-defined dimension?

Tags: category-theory, cardinals, monads

Let $(T,\mu,\eta)$ be a nontrivial monad on $\mathbf{Set}$. By nontrivial here I mean there is $X$ with $|T(X)|>1$.

Suppose that $TX \cong TY$ as $T$-algebras (both with the usual free $T$-algebra structure). Does it then follow that $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality ? (Which we could then define as the dimension of the free $T$-algebra, by analogy with vector spaces).

I think the motivation for this question is pretty clear (analogy with vector spaces, lots of examples), here are my thoughts :

- all the examples I know satisfy this property : vector spaces over a fixed field $k$, or more generally $R$-modules, groups,  boolean algebras, the ultrafilter monad, the powerset monad,...
- If the monad $T$ is furthermore finitary, that is it preserves (as an endofunctor) filtered colimits, then the claim is true when either $X$ or $Y$ is infinite, this is not totally straightforward but not hard to show, I will add the details at the end of the question (*)
- If the monad has at least one finite $T$-algebra with cardinality $>1$, then the claim holds when either $X$ or $Y$ is finite. This is easy, details at (**).

-If the monad has $T$-algebras of arbitrary infinite cardinalities, then the claim holds when either $X$ or $Y$ is infinite. This relies on some (easy) cardinal arithmetic and will be detailed at (***)

- $T$ being nontrivial implies that it always reflects isomorphisms, which is weaker than what we want. This is standard and not too hard,  but I think the post is already long enough, so unless specifically asked to I will not detail this.

-In the examples I gave one can notice that there are 2 extremely different behaviours : in the case of monoids, the ultrafilter monad, or the powerset monad, isomorphisms are "created", in the sense that an isomorphism of $T$-algebras between $TX$ and $TY$ always comes from a bijection $X\to Y$; whereas in other cases such as vector spaces or groups, there can be other isomorphisms, but there *is* a bijection between $X$ and $Y$.

For the first behaviour, one can see that this is because somehow the monad is "positive", one can not cancel the "atoms" (elements of $TX$ of the form $\eta_X(x)$), and they are the only ones with this property.

This leads me to think one could define a notion of "positive monad" for which the proof would be easy, but I have not yet found the right definition (the ones I find either don't work or seem ad hoc). The idea would be that elements of the form $\eta_X(x)$ are precisely the $z$'s such that if $\mu_X(a)=z$, then $a=\eta_{TX}(z)$. The thing is, any algebraic characterization of these elements will give this behaviour, because then we can ensure that the isomorphism comes from a morphism $X\to Y$ and then the previous point (about reflecting isomorphisms) solves the question.

For the second behaviour (vector spaces and "weird" isomorphisms), I don't really know how to attack the problem.

So my questions are, more specifically : is the result true in all generality, and if so, how can one prove it ? Could it be valid for nice categories other than $\mathbf{Set}$ (with an appropriate notion of nontriviality) ? If not, what are some nice conditions on $T$ that ensure that the result holds ? Are any of them similar to the vague idea of positivity that I tried to describe ?

EDIT : As was pointed out in the comments, it is not true for all monads, indeed there are some *noncommutative* rings without the IBP, and so it fails for finitely generated free modules. However, since $R$ modules always give a finitary monad, it still holds for infinitely generated free algebras, and so two questions remain : is it always true for infinitely generated free algebras ? (I now suspect that it is false) and what are some nice conditions on $T$ that yield a positive result ?

(*) this is essentially the same proof as for vector spaces : if $T$ is finitary, $X$ infinite and $f:TX\cong TY$ then for any $x\in X$, there is a finite $Y_x\subset Y$ with $f(\eta_X(x))\in TY_x$ and since $T$ is nontrivial, it reflects epimorphisms (this is standard and I will not detail it unless specifically asked to) so that $\bigcup_x Y_x = Y$. Therefore $|Y|\leq \aleph_0 |X|$, the converse holding as well. It is clear that by a similar argument, $Y$ is infinite so that these inequalities imply $|X|=|Y|$.

This can be adapted to $<\kappa$-ary monads and sets of cardinality $\geq \kappa$ in an obvious manner but it didn't seem worth it to mention it.

(**) Suppose $h: TA\to A$ is a finite $T$-algebra with $|A|\geq 2$, suppose $X$ is finite and $TX\cong TY$ as $T$-algebras. Then the universal property of free algebras yields that $A^X \cong A^Y$ as sets. But $X$ is finite and $|A|\geq 2$ so $Y$ is finite as well and $|X|=|Y|$, therefore there is a bijection.

(* * *) :  We use the universal property of free algebras as for ( * *) and the fact that if two cardinals (here $|X|, |Y|$) have the same continuum function $\mu \mapsto \mu^\kappa$ on infinite cardinals $\mu$, then they are equal, cf the answer to my previous post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317071/408637)

Comment: Free $R$-modules [do not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number#Examples) have well-defined dimension in general.

Comment: @user54748 : right ! I was thinking of commutative rings ! Thank you ! So there *is* a need for more properties

Comment: Yes, but the question is interesting. Maybe some of the necessary conditions for rings generalize to other monads?

Comment: @user54748 : I agree that my interest in the question has not completely vanished (despite your devastating comment ;) ), and as I pointed out I'm still interested in nice conditions on the monad that make it true. Your comment has opened up a second route to finding conditions (which seems remote from my "positive monad" idea)

Comment: Well, since I'm already bringing bad news, I'll also add that I wouldn't be very optimistic about generalizations to other categories. Eg. in Ab, $R$-modules are again an example (functors $R ⊗ -$ are exactly the cocontinuous monads) but the failure to reflect isomorphicity is a lot more dramatic ($ℤ_2 ⊗ ℤ_p = 0$ for odd $p$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is in fact a "universal" example where this fails for any given cardinals.  Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and define an *$(A,B)$-Jónsson-Tarski algebra* be a set $X$ equipped with an $A$-ary operation $f_b:X^A\to X$ for each $b\in B$ and a $B$-ary operation $g_a:X^B\to X$ for each $a\in A$ satisfying the equational axioms that say the induced maps $f:X^A\to X^B$ and $g:X^B\to X^A$ are inverse bijections.  (For $|A|=1$ and $|B|=2$, this is the usual notion of a [Jónsson-Tarski algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3nsson%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra).)  Observe now that a free $(A,B)$-Jónsson-Tarski algebra on $A$ is the same thing as a free $(A,B)$-Jónsson-Tarski algebra on $B$, since $f$ and $g$ give a natural bijection between functions $A\to X$ and functions $B\to X$ for any $(A,B)$-Jónsson-Tarski algebra $X$.

Moreover, suppose $T$ is any monad on $\mathbf{Set}$ and $f:TB\to TA$ be an isomorphism of $T$-algebras.  Then $f$ induces a natural bijection $X^A\to X^B$ for any $T$-algebra $X$, giving every $T$-algebra the structure of an $(A,B)$-Jónsson-Tarski algebra such that all $T$-algebra homomorphisms are also $(A,B)$-Jónsson-Tarski algebra homomorphisms.  This then induces a morphism of monads $J\to T$ where $J$ is the free $(A,B)$-Jónsson-Tarski algebra monad, and it is straightforward to check that this construction is reversible and thus gives a natural bijection between isomorphisms of $T$-algebras $TB\to TA$ and monad morphisms $J\to T$.  That is, $J$ is the free monad on $\mathbf{Set}$ with an isomorphism $JB\to JA$.

Comment: Wow thank you ! I never would have thought of that. I will wait before accepting your answer, because of course there are still things to be said, but thank you very much !